audience upload to a custom audience on FB is not matching with phone numbers
the problem i have is that sync phone numbers through api cannot be done except if we hashed those phone numbers, when we hash those phone numbers FB will not be able to recognize and match the users and in the estimated audience size we will have below 1000 always and size will be always ---, i tried to change the format of the phone numbers and make them without + sign but it gave the same result unfortunately. i thought that maybe the phone numbers we are uploading has no FB accounts and because of that FB is not able to recognize them but when i uploaded them manually without hashing to FB audience list using FB panel there was matching and i got numbers in the estimated audience size when i tried to hash those same phone numbers and uploaded them manually but hashed to an audience list in FB panel i got the same issue (no recognition) i am hashing using the same method we are using for email (with email there is no issues and everything works as expected) i am using SHA256 for hashing as FB suggested in their documentation. and i am sending phone numbers with country code as FB suggests in their documentation so basically i am doing everything as they listed in their documentation but we are getting no fulfilling or satisfying results with matching. (PS: i am sending all the users and FB is not giving any errors while uploading those users.).
i tried to change the format of the uploaded phone numbers (i uploaded with and without + sign), i am using php laravel in my main project but i tried to hash and upload through golang but i got the same result. also i am normalizing the phone numbers as they listed in the documentation i am sending only numbers without any symbols and leading zeros.
i expect to have audience size when phone numbers uploaded similar to what it happen when emails are uploaded to an audience list.
audience size after upload to audience list manually
audience size after upload to audience list through api

there was an issue in my hashing, i resolved the issue and seems everything is good now.
